# Remote call of NRPE comman fails in one case, while succeeding locally in all

Tags: nagios, selinux, rhel7, nrpe

I have amazingly strange issue with monitoring a CIFS (SMB) shared folder mounted to Linux machines by Nagios + NRPE.

NRPE process runs on the Linux machines under dedicated user `nrpe`:

```
# systemctl status nrpe
  nrpe.service - Nagios Remote Program Executor
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nrpe.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-05-02 14:46:47 IDT; 20h ago
     Docs: http://www.nagios.org/documentation
  Process: 30216 ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /run/nrpe/nrpe.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30218 (nrpe)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nrpe.service
           └─30218 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -f

# ps -ef | grep nrpe
nrpe     30218     1  0 May02 ?        00:00:05 /usr/sbin/nrpe -c /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg -f
```

The monitoring command is defined in its configuration `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` file this way:

```
command[check_backups_share]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 7% -c 5% -p /mnt/backups
```

If I run the command manually as `nrpe` user on all machines, it succeeds:

```
# sudo -u nrpe bash
bash-4.2$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk -w 7% -c 5% -p /mnt/backups
DISK OK - free space: /mnt/backups 2571991 MiB (61.32% inode=-);| /mnt/backups=1622248MiB;3900643;3984528;0;4194240
```

**However**, if I call it *remotely* from Nagios, it succeeds on one machine and fails on another:

```
$ /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -2 -H Machine01 -c check_backups_share
DISK OK - free space: /mnt/backups 2575536 MiB (61.40% inode=-);| /mnt/backups=1618703MiB;3900643;3984528;0;4194240

$ /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -2 -H Machine02 -c check_backups_share
DISK CRITICAL - /mnt/backups is not accessible: Permission denied
```

All other remote NRPE commands on `Machine02` succeed. Even more, if I unmount the `/mnt/backups` folder on `Machine02`, it also succeeds (for root filesystem).
But when it's mounted, I get this `Permission denied` error.

The folder is mounted identically on all machines, with the same credentials and options. In `/etc/fstab` file:

```
//Backups-Server/backups  /mnt/backups      cifs    vers=3.0,credentials=/path/to/creds    0 0
```

So:

- all credentials, permissions, users, groups are the same;
- command executed locally on all machines under the same user produces the same results;
- but when executed remotely, it fails on one machine complaining on permissions, but succeeds on all others,
- while the executing `nrpe` process configured the same way on all machines and has the same permissions.

So what on earth could this be?

**Update:**

Solved, see below.

Comment: Extraordinary statements require extraordinary proofs. "Identical"? Well, what distro is it? On each machine, show `ls -la` on *mounted* share, `ls -Z` to see SELinux if it's applicable (don't assume, *check* it with `sestatus`), and `getfacl` with appropriate attributes. (I'd also check `getattr`, just for case.) Finally, hadn't you just forget to restart `nrpe` after making changes to configuration?

Comment: Thanks, @NikitaKipriyanov!

The OS:
`# uname -a: Linux Machine01 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 18 20:25:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`# cat /etc/redhat-release: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)`
```

Comment: `# ls -alZ /mnt/backups/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0      .
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:mnt_t:s0       ..
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0      Machine01
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0      Machine02`

Comment: # getfacl /mnt/backups/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/backups/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

Comment: `# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31`

Comment: All these outputs are identical on both machines, the problematic and the healthy.

Not sure what do you mean by `getattr`, could you please show an example?

Comment: You see yourself this is unreadable. Please, [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1130248/edit) your question and put it there. // As for the problem, I strongly suspect SELinux involvement. Check variables with `semanage boolean -l`. Set it to Permissive (temporarily) and inspect logs; it will log instead of denying action so if it begin working you'll be able to see what exactly prevented it.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, you're absolutely right, SELinux is culpable here - as soon as I set it to Permissive mode with `setenforce Permissive`, the problem disappeard; as soon as I reverted this by `setenforce Enforcing`, it resumed. 

However, when I run `semanage boolean -l` on both machines, it produces exactly the same results (compared with `diff`), and the mode is `Enforcing` on both, the problematic and the healthy one. What else can I check?

Comment: This also helped - `semanage permissive -l nrpe_t`.

Comment: So, while in Permissive, what was logged, what would be rejected if it worked in Restrictive?

Comment: I found this entry in the `journalctl -xe | grep check_disk` output: `May 04 13:19:13 Machine02 kernel: type=1400 audit(1683195553.116:22386): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=24826 comm="check_disk" path="/mnt/backups" dev="cifs" ino=3458764513820542747 scontext=system_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0`. Does this tell you anything?

Comment: Yes. In general, you follow this [procedure with audit2allow](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#Creating_Custom_SELinux_Policy_Modules_with_audit2allow) to create a custom permission. I suggest you to read the whole linked page. I am too lazy to reproduce the problem to demonstrate its use and write an answer, but now I suppose you'll be able to do it yourself.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, thanks a lot! `audit2allow` solved the problem - as far as I understand, it generated a policy allowing processes labeled with `nrpe_t` to access CIFS-mounted folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks to @NikitaKipriyanov, the problem solved.

Found multiple entries in `/var/log/messages`:

```
[root@Machine02 /]# cat /var/log/messages | grep avc | grep check_disk

May  7 17:32:01 Machine02 kernel: type=1400 audit(1683469921.442:63546): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=20931 comm="check_disk" path="/mnt/backups" dev="cifs" ino=3458764513820542747 scontext=system_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

May  7 17:32:21 Machine02 kernel: type=1400 audit(1683469941.508:63549): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=20973 comm="check_disk" path="/mnt/backups" dev="cifs" ino=3458764513820542747 scontext=system_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

May  7 17:32:41 Machine02 kernel: type=1400 audit(1683469961.575:63552): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=21025 comm="check_disk" path="/mnt/backups" dev="cifs" ino=3458764513820542747 scontext=system_u:system_r:nrpe_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

Generated policy to avoid such denials:

```
[root@Machine02 /]# cat /var/log/messages | grep avc | grep check_disk | audit2allow -M check_disk_policy
```

This produced two files:

- `check_disk_policy.pp` - binary
- `check_disk_policy.te` - textual, containing this:

```
module nrpe 1.0;

require {
    type nrpe_t;
    type cifs_t;
    class dir getattr;
}

#============= nrpe_t ==============

#!!!! The file '/mnt/backups' is mislabeled on your system.  
#!!!! Fix with $ restorecon -R -v /mnt/backups
allow nrpe_t cifs_t:dir getattr;
```

Running `restorecon -R -v /mnt/backups` didn't help, so I loaded the policy:

```
[root@Machine02 /]# semodule -i check_disk_policy.pp
```

After that the error disappeared. As I understand, this policy allows processes labeled with `nrpe_t` (the `/usr/sbin/nrpe` process and children processes spawned by it, such as `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk`) to access CIFS shared folders.